# Como a conjunção "mas" derivou do Latim "magis"?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, advérbios, conjunções

De acordo com o [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mas#Etymology_11), as palavras “mas” e “mais” são cognatos:

> From Old Portuguese *mas*, from Latin *magis* ‎(“more”), from Proto-Indo-European **meǵh₂-* ‎(“great”). Cognate of *mais* ‎(“more”).

Como ocorreu esta derivação? Mais precisamente, eu gostaria de ver exemplos das primeiras instâncias de uso de “mais” como conjunção.

Comment: Segundo Sai Ali, a "substituição de _sed_, _autem_, por _mais_ (depois _mas_), do advérbio _ma(g)is_, data do período pré-lusitano" (_Gramática Histórica_, §1099).

Comment: @Artefacto Sabes o quais são os períodos lusitano e pré-lusitano?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Explica o dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) que ***mas*** vem (desabreviando as abreviaturas) do

> português arcaico *mais* e, este, do latim *magis*; o valor adversativo originou-se do facto de, em muitos contextos em que se usava esta partícula, a ideia de adversativa estar implícita, do que resultou a fixação desse sentido na partícula

A palavra francesa *mais* (*mas* em português), vem também de *magis*, como seria de esperar. O [Centre National de Ressources Textuelle et Lexicales](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/mais) explica que *magis* já havia assumido o valor de *mas* no latim (tradução minha):

> Do sentido secundário [de *magis*] «de preferência, antes», nomeadamente nas construções *non … sed magis* [*não … mas mais/antes*], *ac magis*, *magis autem* […] veio o emprego adversativo (*cf*. primeiro na linguagem poética CÁTULO [84 – 54 a.C.], 68 30: *id. … non est turpe magis miserum est* [*não é torpe, mais/antes miserável*]; em prosa a partir de SALÚSTIO [86 – 34 a.C.], *Jug*., 96, 2: *ab nullo repetere* [*sc. benficia*] *magis id laborare ut*… [*não pedia nada em troca [de favores], mas/antes fazia o que podia*...]), os seus representantes românicos […] mostrando que *magis* tinha desde a época pré-românica assumido os empregos de *sed* (oposição forte) e de *autem* (oposição fraca);

Ainda segundo o Houaiss os primeiros registos conhecidos de *mais*, também grafado *mays*, quer no sentido de ‘mas’ quer do atual ‘mais’ são do século XIII. (Chegou-nos pouquíssimo material em português de séculos anteriores.) E encontramos imensos exemplos na poesia medieval do século XIII no [Corpo Informático do Português Medieval](http://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/). Também já se usava *mas*. O mais curioso é que *mais* ou *mays* aparecem na mesma cantiga, por vezes no mesmo verso, ora com um significado ora com outro. Eis alguns exemplos (ênfase minha; cada estrofe é de uma cantiga diferente):

[image]

Agora o que eu gostaria era de entrar na cabeça do pessoal do século XIII para saber se os dois sentidos de *mais* se lhe apresentavam completamente distintos (como os de *porca* para nós, *o diabo da porca engoliu parafuso, porca e tudo*) ou se mais como os de *antes* ou *já*, que nós empregamos com dois sentidos sem necessariamente nos darmos conta; ou, quando damos, detetamos uma ligação entre eles, como em:

> **Antes** quero levantar-me mais cedo do que chegar ele **antes** de mim
>
> Eles **já** chegaram. A Maria vem bem disposta; **já** o João vem com cara de poucos amigos

Comment: Se algum latinista puder rever a minha tradução de *non est turpe magis miserum est* e traduzir *ab nullo repetere [sc. benficia] magis id laborare ut*, a comissão agradece.

Comment: Your translation is correct (and +1 for your answer). Unfortunately, I can't write in Portuguese, but here is the translation in English: "he asked no-one to repay [favours], [but] rather did what he could to...".

Comment: @Cerberus Fantastic, I'm now going to translate it to Portuguese now.

Comment: Gostei. Apesar das diferenças entre o original e a tua tradução, Jacinto, os modos de escrever são quase idênticos. Digo quase porque a coluna onde é escrita o original, me parecia também o espanhol. Exemplo: verbo crer (traduzido também como acreditar, na segunda coluna)

Comment: @tucas Eu mudei o *creerey* para *acreditar* por não gostar muito/estar habituado ao futuro do verbo crer: na Idade Média devia soar melhor que agora; *creerei* dantes, *crerei* agora. Ainda por cima, no meu sotaque, *crerei* confunde-se com a dicção rápida de *quererei*.

Comment: Verdade. Se se pronuncia crerei de forma rápida é bem parecida à forma  falada de quererei, na pronúncia portuguesa, embora existindo no Brasil, quase não a usamos. Se usamos esta forma verbal de querer, é muito raro.